# Efficiency using insert with a map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert

There's [an example on cplusplus.com reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) that I'm not understanding.

In the following example, when C is inserted, why is that less efficient than inserting B? What's different about them?

```
  // second insert function version (with hint position):
  std::map<char,int>::iterator it = mymap.begin();
  mymap.insert (it, std::pair<char,int>('b',300));  // max efficiency inserting
  mymap.insert (it, std::pair<char,int>('c',400));  // no max efficiency inserting
```

Comment: What article is this from?

Comment: From cplusplus.com: *The function optimizes its insertion time if position points to the element that will precede the inserted element.* b will likely slot in right after a. c is not as lucky. Before you spend much time on this, consider the cost of finding the insertion point if you don't already know it.

Comment: @0x499602D2 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/

Comment: I assume, initially there is no element in the tree, that's why inserting `b` would be with the maximum efficiency. However, after then, comparisons of elements and balancing of the tree must be made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That example is  using the overload of `insert` that accepts a "hint" iteration to say in what part of the backing binary tree the new element should be inserted.  The example implies `it` - which was initialised to `begin()` - is as good a hint as possible when inserting into an empty table, but less useful (perhaps not useful at all) when inserting a second element.

I'm not sure why that website (which historically hasn't been very good - I trust cppreference.com far more), makes the efficiency assertion about the insertion of `'b'`.  The Standard's requirements are (with `p` being the hint iterator):

> The element is inserted as close as possible to the position just prior to `p`.

A position prior to `begin()` doesn't exist.  If anything,  it's likely to be more efficient not to provide a hint for the first `insert`.

During the second `insert`, `'b'` is at `begin()` and we don't want to `insert` `'c'` "just prior to" `'b'`, so the Standard's "as close as possible" kicks in and the `insert` can be expected to grope around for the correct place despite the hint.

More generally, hints get useful when the tree has many more elements, so the `insert` implementation can just check a couple elements near the hint to ensure order without working its way down from the root of the binary tree.